How to check the index REORGANIZE progress
I have some query that till now helped me to check index rebuild progress but it doesn't show the REORGANIZE progress. I mean reorganizing index (at this case clustered) like this:
ALTER INDEX IX_Index_CL ON TableName
REORGANIZE

Queries that I found at internet forums didnt help.
The only query that shows something is:
SELECT percent_complete, * 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests 
WHERE session_id ='my session'

But looks like it shows the wrong info.

That's only available view to get progress of a query, Unlike REBUILD ,REORGANIZE is a resumable operation hence any time you can stop and later continue from where you stopped with the same command.

You can find a couple of empirical formulas in this article. It is, however, in Russian - you will have to translate it.

You could use sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats view to check current fragmentation of the index. However, the progress of the REORGANIZE is not exactly linear.
DECLARE @dbId INT = DB_ID(),
    @objectId INT = OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable');

DECLARE @indexId INT = (
        SELECT index_id
        FROM sys.indexes
        WHERE [object_id] = @objectId
            AND [name] = 'MyIndex'
    )

SELECT avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (
   @dbId
  ,@objectId
  ,@indexId
  ,NULL
  ,NULL
)

